# [Material-UI@v5]: using css classes api of components with emotion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I'm wondering what's the proper way to go about using emotion with the classes api of components in version 5.

Since `@material-ui` is a react lib, I'm mostly using the `@emotion/react` package, but the classes api expects a string value for its keys, so I have to use the `@emotion/css` to generate a string className.

```
  <Button
    classes={{
      root: css({
        margin
      }),
    }}
  >
    Click me!
  </Button>
```

I have two issues:

1. It doesn't seem quite right to be jumping between the two packages like this. Is there a better solution?
2. [The rtl-guide in `@material-ui` docs](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/) instructs us to use the [`stylis-plugin-rtl`](https://github.com/styled-components/stylis-plugin-rtl); The stlyes generated with `@emotion/react` are transformed correctly, but the one generated with `@emotion/css` do not get flipped using this plugin.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `classes` API is primarily included in v5 for backwards compatibility (e.g. for those with heavy use of `makeStyles` in their code), but is not the primary customization approach recommended for v5. I think you will find the most of the examples in the documentation (e.g. https://next.material-ui.com/components/buttons/#customized-buttons) use the `styled` API.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Is what you're saying about `classes` being a legacy api mentioned anywhere in the migration guide? 

Of course you're right, I could use the `styled` api, but I don't really want to create separate components every time I want to style 'em differently, I think that makes the codebase a lil' bit messy!

Comment: If you don’t want to use the styled API, the other main options are the new `sx` prop or use Emotion directly via the `css` prop.